Encountering error with Loading in Powershell trying to run XSLT script
I'm trying to see if I can run an XSLT transform (in my case XML to XML) via PowerShell in Windows 10.
I've found various examples, and have tried variations of each. I seem to be stuck on the Load command, where it loads the input XSLT file.
It breaks on the .Load command (Line 18) - specifically saying "Exception calling "Load"...
I've tried it with one argument and, now with 3 arguments (per samples/recommendations found).
One additional question is whether I should expect this to work if my XSLT has include statements. There are 3 other XSL files being referenced. (I'm planning to physically include them to avoid that problem if this approach can't handle include statements.)
Using the various previous answers - I have the following code:
(Any help would be appreciated!)
$XSLTPath = "C:\MyPath\"
$OutPath = "$XSLTPath\OutPath\"

$XMLFileName = "Input.xml"
$XMLInputFile = $OutPath + $XMLFileName
$OutputFileName = "Output.xml"
$XMLOutputFile = $OutPath + $OutputFileName

$XSLFileName = "MyXSLT.xslt"
$XSLFileInput = $XSLTPath + $XSLFileName

$xslt_settings = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XsltSettings;
$XmlUrlResolver = New-Object System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver;
$xslt_settings.EnableDocumentFunction = 1;
#$xslt_settings.EnableScript = 1;

$xslt = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform;
$xslt.Load($XSLFileInput, $xslt_settings, $XmlUrlResolver);

$XMLInputDoc = Get-Content -Path $XMLInputFile

$reader = [System.Xml.XmlReader]::Create($XMLInputFile)
$writer = [System.Xml.XmlTextWriter]::Create($XMLOutputFile)

$XSLInputElement.Transform($XMLInputFile, $XMLOutputFile)


If you want us to tell what fails you have to post minimal but complete samples (including the XSLT) to allow us to easily reproduce the problem.

The XML is probably invalid.  Use an online XML validation tool to verify the XML is valid.

OK - so the problem isn't with the process of loading itself, you expect it is not liking what it is seeing in the file. The reason that never crossed my mind is because the file I'm trying to use has been used, validated, etc. before with no issues. But I will give it a closer look. Thanks!

Sorry for my typo in the original question. The load error is on the .Load command - which loads the XSLT file (not the XML file to be processed). Since it is a tried-and-true transform file, I never imagined the problem would be with that file itself. (I cannot post the XSLT as it is too big and also probably just not allowed.)
Can I glean from the message what the problem is? It outputs:

CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException

FullyQualifiedErrorId : XslLoadException




Does Powershell have some try/catch statement? In C# I would use that around the Load call.

Which version of Powershell is that, the Windows only/.NET framework (tends to be Powershell 5 these days) or the cross platform .NET core (tends to be Powershell 7 these days) that you are running the code with? Does that XSLT try to use msxsl:script with embedded C# or VB code? I think the .NET Core version of XslCompiledTransform doesn't support that.

I’m not sure about the try/catch thing. I’ll look into that.

As far as the Powershell version, I don’t know, and I’d have to go figure out how to look. Ha. The XSLT does not do any msxsl:script or VB etc., but it does “include” other XSLT files.
